# Adding a new node to an existing SQL cluster

Tags: sql-server, windows-server, failovercluster

I am new to fail-over clustering, I have a two node Windows fail-over cluster (windows server 2016) with SQL Server 2016 Installed in cluster mode which configured successfully and everything is working fine. I needed to configure an Always-On Availability to a DR site, but ended up in error while adding the third node.

I have uninstalled Antivirus,checked for duplicate name in the AD of which there are non and it didn't fix my problem.

> Cluster service on node xxxxxxxx did not reach the running state. The error code is 0x5b4. For more information check the cluster log and the system event log from node **xxxxxx**. This operation returned because the timeout period expired.
>
> Operation failed, attempting cleanup.
>
> The server 'xxxxxx.xxx.net' could not be added to the cluster. An error occurred while adding node 'xxxxxx.xxxx.net' to cluster 'xxxxxx'.
>
> This operation returned because the timeout period expired

From the event viewer in failover cluster manager it says xxxxx has been evicted from the cluster.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should first run following PowerShell command

Clear-ClusterNode -Name nodeName -Force

After running this command  try to add node back to the cluster

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score -1):

Have You tried to add third server from Failover Cluster Manager (FCM) i.e. have you spinned the Role/Server from FCM or from Hyper V manager. Please try to spin Vm from FCM